# D3 bar chart to stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart, stacked-chart

Hi i'm new to D3 and I'm trying to convert a normal bar chart to a stacked bar chart.

This is my code

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42, 200];

var height = 200;
var width = 200;
var barWidth = 35;
var barOffset = 5;

var myChart = d3.select(".chart").append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.style("background", "grey")
.selectAll('rect')
.data(data)
.enter().append('rect').
style("fill", "blue")
.attr("width", barWidth)
.attr("height", function(d){ return d;})
.attr('x', function(d, i) 
      { return i *(barWidth + barOffset);})
.attr('y', function(d){
  return height - d;
});
```

Any help or hint in to the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a simple thing to do. You have to calculate relative positions of your stacked rectangles. Find an example of a stacked bar-chart (or a tutorial) and start from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just for the comment on above answer..

here is the code  -

```js
var data = [
 [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42, 200],
 [50, 60, 20, 100, 30, 50, 40]
 ];
//console.log(data)

//console.log("REMAP---------------------------");
var remapped =data[0].map(function(dat,i){
    return data.map(function(d,ii){
        return {x: ii, y: d[i] };
    })
});


var w = 200,
h = 200

// create canvas
var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h )
.append("svg:g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0,"+h+")");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.5)
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h])
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]).domain(data[0].map(function(d,i){return i;}));



//console.log("LAYOUT---------------------------");
var stacked = d3.layout.stack()(remapped)
//console.log(stacked)

x.domain(stacked[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(stacked[stacked.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

// show the domains of the scales              
console.log("x.domain(): " + x.domain())
console.log("y.domain(): " + y.domain())


// Add a group for each column.
var valgroup = svg.selectAll("g.valgroup")
.data(stacked)
.enter().append("svg:g")
.attr("class", "valgroup")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
.style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(color(i)).darker(); });

// Add a rect for each date.
var rect = valgroup.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d){return d;})
.enter().append("svg:rect")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
.attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
.attr("width", x.rangeBand());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here data plays an important role.
You need to modify the data, compatible with the chart type.

Here is the solution for your problem.

hope, this will surely help you. thanks :)

```js
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42, 200];

data = data.map(function(d) { return [{x: 0, y: d}] });

var stack = d3.layout.stack();
var stackData = stack(data);
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]).domain(data.map(function(d,i){return i;}));

var height = 200;
var width = 200;
var barWidth = 35;
var barOffset = 5;

var lastData = stackData[stackData.length-1][0]; //to get the max value
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]).domain([0, lastData.y+lastData.y0]);

var myChart = d3.select(".chart").append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.style("fill", "grey")
.selectAll('rect')
.data(stack(data))
.enter().append('rect').
style("fill", function(d,i) { 
 return color(i); 
})
.attr("width", barWidth)
.attr('x', 0)
.attr("y", function(d) { 
 return y(d[0].y0+d[0].y); 
})
.attr("height", function(d) { 
 return height - y(d[0].y); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

yes!! ideally stacked bar chart must require a **2D** array

following are few scenarios that will makes your understanding clear

**scenario 1 -**

we need to visualise sales of MAC(only one product) for 5 years

then the data will be : sales: [$2000, $5555, $20177, $9999, $80805]

*so here we need simple bar chart, where each bar will show the sales in respective year*

**senario 2 -**

we need to visualise sales of 3 products(MAC, iPad, iPhone) for 5 years
then the data will be :

sales of MAC: [$2000, $5555, $20177, $9999, $80805]

sales of iPad: [$2000, $5555, $20177, $9999, $80805]

sales of iPhone: [$2000, $5555, $20177, $9999, $80805]

*here we need stacked bar chat, where each stack will show the sales of 3 products in respective year*

if we have multiple array then.. in addition to above code we need, x scale

you can follow the [exapmle](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208)

hope this will help :) thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have a question if you could so kindly answer. I see that you're creating one bar using an array. How would you create multi bars? Would you need multiple arrays? Sorry in advance if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that. Sorry last question, how would you add another stacked bar. Currently you have 1 bar, how would you add another 1? So sorry again for asking questions. I do appreciate the time and effect you put in to helping me.